# Change an IAP from Non-Renewing subscription to Auto-Renewing

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, transition, subscription

In my app I have a Non-Renewing subscription to access one of the feature.Now my client has asked me to change it to Auto-Renewing subscription, I am confused on how to start the same. Should I change the existing to product or should I remove the Non-Renewing & add a new Auto-Renewable item. 1000's of user are already purchased the product as Non-Renewable, will updating the same cause any problem for them. Can anyone please guide me on how to implement it.

Comment: You can't change an existing product.  You will need to create a new product and remove the old one from sale.  You will need to coordinate this with a new version of your app that supports the auto-renewing subscription

Comment: thanks Paulw11, when should I delete the existing Non-Renewing item. Is it after the Apple's approval of new Renewing item or before submitting the new item. what should be the correct way.

Comment: You can delete it once your new version is live, but be aware that people who haven't upgraded won't be able to purchase the new product and won't be able to purchase the old product once it is deleted

Comment: @Paulw11 one more question I am new to IAP, do I need to submit my new Auto-Renewal item & App Update separately in itunes connect or it will be automatically submitted with my new App version submission.

Comment: @Paulw11,  One more question from my end, i.e I have created Auto renewable products and testing in sandbox environment. My question is  I have purchased one product, and If I try to purchase same product with same Apple account it is showing alert as already purchased as expected but I could not able to fetch that transaction details as it is executing failed state  in updated transactions.  How I can get that  purchased details (like receiptID, receipt Data) as we get in Initial transaction.

Comment: You have to wait until the first subscription expires and doesn't renew; this happens at an accelerated rate in the sandbox. Once you can purchase it again the new purchase will be added to the receipt as with all of the renewed events

Comment: thanks @Paulw11 . but the scenario what I am looking for is, User has already purchased the auto-renewable item. And again if user purchases the same item with the same apple id, I am getting an alert saying 'You have already purchased this item' and that is fine. But I need the original transaction/purchase receipt. When user try to purchase the same item, it is executing the transaction failed delegate, but I have a requirement to get the original purchase receipt. Kindly let me know how to get the original purchase receipt if you are aware.

Comment: my  Scenario is I have 2 screens, Products purchase & Registration screen. Once I have purchased product, using that receipt information I will move to registration screen there I will create My app account. If I have purchased and I got receipt details, it will navigate to Registration screen and I closed my app. Test case: I purchased in one device, I opened same app in other device there If I want create account with the same apple id.I need the already made transaction receipt. When I try to purchase the item, it shows me you have already purchased but I am not getting the receipt.

Comment: How are checking the receipt?  As I said, You can't purchase again until the current subscription is not renewed (In the sandbox autorenew stops after a while).  You can use the "restore" function in StoreKit to get the active subscriptions on another device or you can just refresh the receipt.  See also https://github.com/paulw11/subscription-monitor

Comment: @Paulw11is there any way where I can get the first transaction receipt later (successful purchase).  because I have to use that receipt details to create user account. for the first time when user purchases the item, because of some reason if I am unable to create the user account for my application, I need to get the receipt later to create account. How to fetch that receipt gain.

Comment: Yes, the receipt always contains the full purchase history, including expired subscriptions.  The format of the receipt is described in the in-app purchase programming guide.

Comment: but how to get the receipt, because user has already purchased the item, at that I couldnt able create the account because of some reason. when the user is trying to create, how to get/fetch already purchased item receipt. To get it user is trying to click on the purchase button again, but it is giving an alert saying 'you have already purchased this item' and transaction failed delegate is getting executed. how to get that receipt again

Comment: Either using the restore purchases function (provide a restore button in your UI for this purpose) or refresh the receipt. When testing with a sandbox account you must signin to this account in the device settings. You cannot sign in during the purchase process as you can with a real account.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11  I have one more issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542461/ios-in-app-purchase-sandbox-test-account-keeps-popping-up-for-verification      please help me in sorting out as I am stuck in middle.