# iOS In-App Purchase sandbox test account keeps popping up for verification

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, sandbox, auto-renewable

I have Auto-Renewable In-App Purchase item in my application which is in development stage. I could able to test the complete transaction till 2 days ago with different sandbox test accounts (+abc@def.com). From past couple of days when I am trying to test the transaction with new sandbox test accounts (+abc345@def.com), it is giving me an alert saying **AppleID Verification - Open settings to continue signing with ******+abc345@def.com**. I have already verified the account before trying to purchase. I have tried and tested with numerous new accounts I have created, getting the same alert message. When I googled the issue, got suggestions to create a sandbox account with different AppStore locations Like Canada, UK....etc. but didn't worked out for me. 
Could anyone help, as I am struck in testing my transaction process.
[image]

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue. Have never seen this until now. I was getting [this Sandbox signup error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496572/java-lang-nullpointerexception-error-when-adding-sandbox-tester-in-itunes-connec/41496866) a few days ago, and now that signup is working again it seems they've changed something on their side.

Answer (score 2):

Came to know this is an issue from Apple side, which they are aware of now and working on it.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/204979#204979

Comment: I wonder how long this fix will take. We urgently need to test in-app purchases, but this annoying issue prevents us from keeping the time schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it's working, sort of.

1. Make a fresh sandbox account.
2. Confirm it after receiving the email
3. Login in your app
4. If a Change password dialog appears, then change your password you confirmed a few seconds ago...
5. ...and then it works.

Don't try to use accounts you have made the past few days before 13 January 2017, these are currently unusable.

Answer (score 0):

no idea I have created multiple sandbox users never found this issue ever

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/204979#204979

Its working great...
1. You need to create another test id from your iTunes account. 
2. It will prompt to signing to settings. 
3. Go there and change the password. 
4. Now come back to app. and purchase any item. It will allow you to buy that item...